# Xamarin.Android app reported crash with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Exception

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

First upon all this is not a duplicate question or have been answered on stackoverflow or xamarin forums. On xamarin forums this problem/question is still under discussion so i have posted it here.

So the problem with my app and also bunch of others which have been developed in Xamarin.Android reporting crashes (opt-in and opt-out) on Google's play console.

App actually not crashing. It just reporting automated crash reports to Google's play console.

Following is crash **Stack Traces for Android 6.0 and 7.0**  :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

**In Android 5.1 and 5.0  :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
```

**For Android 4.2 and 4.4 :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
```

Seems this exception occurring majorly in Android 6.0 and 7.0. Above is the only stack traces google play console provided for my and other developers app. There is not any detailed trace available yet.

**For my app, crash reported whenever notification received on app. It impacting all of the app users at exact same time when they received notification.**

Images of crash reports at the time of notification recieved

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following is the my FCM code :

**MainActivity**  :

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var instanceid = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
            instanceid.DeleteInstanceId();
            Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceid.Token, instanceid.GetToken(this.GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));
        });
```

**Token Registration** :

```
 [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] {
    "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"
})]
class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token) { }  

}
```

**OnMessageReceived** :

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] {
    "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"
})]
class MyFireMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);

        var title = string.Empty;
        if (message.Data.Count > 0)
        {
            //Log.Debug(Tag, "Message data payload: " + message.Data);
            title = message.Data["title"];
        }

        SendNotificatios(title);
    }
    public void SendNotificatios( string Header)
    {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
       // builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon));
        builder.SetContentTitle(Header);
        builder.SetPriority(1);
        builder.SetContentText("read more..");
        builder.SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
        builder.SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + Application.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.demonstrative));
        builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
        Random r = new Random();
        int uniw = r.Next(1, 10);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(uniw, builder.Build());

    }
}
```

**Note :** Notification works fine, just whenever notification arrived app reported crash to Google play console.

Please if anyone have any knowledge related to this problem will be helpful. TIA

Comment: Since this happened when your app receive remote notification, one solution is that if received notifications when app hadn't been started up, tried to start up first, and caught exceptions if appeared, then saved the notifications, after user opened app, sent the notifications from native.

Comment: it doesn't matter,if app is open or closed. App still automatically reports crash to google play. Also exception throwing at run time and it's not logging in debug.

Comment: Yeath, and you could read this : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56653

Comment: i have read it already before posting question. As you can see in that thread there is not any sure fix.

Comment: Nothing on this?